# sqlalchemy "incomplete format" problems

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sql-like

I'm using sqlalchemy as a drop in replacement to MySQLdb, that means I'm using session.execute rather than using mappers.

However I've run into a reproducible error, namely an ValueError: "incomplete format" exception wherever I use "%" in a query, this is a problem since the "%" character is necessary for date formatting of UNIX_TIMESTAMP and the LIKE statement in MySQL.

I have tried using "\%", "\\%" and "%%" without luck.

Comment: a code sample would be quite helpful

Answer (score 3):

In concrete case you can use the methods:[contains()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains), [startswith()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.startswith), [endswith()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.endswith)

For illustrate how use it:

```
session.query(Users).filter(User.full_name.startswith('Mr.%s' % first_name))) 
# => It is equivalent to requesting full_name LIKE 'Mr.user1%'

session.query(Users).filter(User.full_name.endswith('%s.' % last_name))) 
# => It is equivalent to requesting full_name LIKE '%user1.'

session.query(Users).filter(User.full_name.contains('%s' % middle_name))) 
# => It is equivalent to requesting full_name LIKE '%user1%'
```